# Chrome 59 Incognito session doesn't expose "Allow" for Notification content settings and defaults to "Blocked" when permission requested through API

Tags: google-chrome, web-notifications, incognito-mode

Chrome `Version 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)` (at least on OSX) behaves differently from 58 in that in an **incognito session**, a call to request permission through the browser Notification API does not show the user the permission request popup; instead, it will automatically and silently set the permission from `default` to `blocked`.

Furthermore, in the the normal content settings UI beside the URL bar, the option to to "Always allow on this site" is missing from the Notification Permission option dropdown.

How can I allow some content like notifications in an Chrome v59 specifically for an incognito session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to allow permission for some content in an incognito session, visit the page in question and let the API permission request to automatically set the permission to blocked, or manually set it to blocked from the browser content permission UI.

Then visit the url `chrome://settings/content` in 
another tab, and click on the content type you want to allow (eg. Notifications). The blocked permission from the incognito session will appear under the section labeled **Block**. Click the little dots on the right of the blocked list item to reveal the permission options, and change it to **Allow**.

[image: A screenshot showing how to change the chrome permission settings to "allow" for an incognito session]

---

Alternatively, on the same chrome settings for a specific content type (eg. Notifications `chrome://settings/content/notifications`), you can click the **ADD** link to the right of the **Allow** section to reveal a popup; enter the url of the site you wish to allow permission for, and check the **Current incognito session only** checkbox.

[image: A screenshot showing how to add a new entry for chrome permission settings for the current incognito session]